# How can I safely pass a value of a variable to a C++ method, which would only take a void* as an argument?

Tags: c++, methods, parameter-passing, void-pointers

I've got a function taking a `void*` as a sole parameter, and also returning `void*`: [gpioThreadFunc_t](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html#gpioThreadFunc_t)

I've now got a variable of type [track_t](https://github.com/xbmc/libcdio/blob/3ffee56e19c18142f07f0e52924c4e7b55d9e11d/include/cdio/types.h#L278), which is basically an `unsigned char`, and would like to call my method with its value (!) as a parameter. In turn, the method must make sure that the argument is really a `track_t` (resp. `unsigned char`) and use it.

I tried to call the method like this:

```cpp
start_thread (Loop, (void *) &track);
```

…where `Loop` is the name of the method, and `track` is the (local) variable in question. When setting its value to 2, the method got 0 or 131 or whatever instead, but not 2.

`Loop` is defined like this:

```cpp
void *Loop (void *params);
```

Does anybody know how I can call my method and pass the necessary argument safely? Or should I forget about parameter passing and rely on a global (or instance) variable instead? Thank you.

**Clarification:** I am still working on my code, so this is NOT a request for debug. I'm asking this question just in order not to run into a pitfall.

Comment: The `void*` cast is unnecessary, but in either case you are passing a pointer to `track`, not the value of `track`, so I don't know what you mean here: "*with its value (!) as a parameter*". It would be helpful if you provided a [repro] showing what code does not pass the argument as you expect.

Comment: The only answers you will get to your question will be random guesses, and nothing more, because the shown code fails to meet all requirements of a [mre], so random guesses is the best you can do. I can think of three or four different reasons that would explain the described issue, and the real reason is probably #5 or #6. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. Until you [edit] your question to include a complete [mre] that anyone can compile, run, and reproduce your issue, nobody will be able to help you. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "safely".    If the called function KNOWS what type is actually being passed, so can cast from the `void` pointer to a type that was actually passed, then the program should function correctly.     However, if there is a non-zero likelihood that the function will be passed something different than it expects, then there is no way to guarantee safety - it is only possible to say that the code will work correctly some percentage of the time.

Comment: @Peter: As the function is **not** part of a solution I'm gonna publish, I can be sure that the data given will be of type ``track_t``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the thread actually needs to access the `track` variable itself (to make alterations to it), then you should just pass the *value* of the `track` variable rather than its *address*.  The *value* of an `unsigned char` easily fits inside the bits of a `void*` pointer:

```
void* Loop(void *params) {
    track_t track = static_cast<track_t>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(params));
    ...
}

...

track_t track = 2;
start_thread(Loop, reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(track)));
```

Otherwise, you can dynamically allocate a `track_t` to pass to the thread, and then free it before the thread exits:

```
void* Loop(void *params) {
    std::unique_ptr<track_t> track(static_cast<track_t*>(params));
    ...
}

...

std::unique_ptr<track_t> track(new track_t(2));
if (start_thread(Loop, track.get()))
    track.release();
```

Comment: That's the point: I don't need any kind of "reverse channel" here as I **only** wanna pass the value of a ``track_t`` variable to the ``Loop`` function, not more.

Comment: @Neppomuk The first example I gave does exactly that.  It stuffs the bits (ie the value) of a `track_t` inside the bits of a `void*` pointer that is then passed to `Loop()` which then extracts the bits back into a `track_t`.

Comment: OK, your suggestion #1 with the `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` provided the solution to my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody know how I can call my method and pass the necessary argument
>
> I tried to call the method like this:
>
> ```
> start_thread (Loop, (void *) &track);
> ```

What you tried would work assuming `Loop` converts the void pointer back to `track_t*` and assuming the pointed `track` object is kept alive until it is no longer used.

The cast to `void*` in your example is unnecessary though, because all object pointers implicitly convert to `void*`.

---

> How can I safely pass a ... void*

It is not possible to make the function that accepts `void*` safe. It is inherently type-unsafe.

What you can do is write a wrapper template that is type safe, and which makes it unnecessary to call `start_thread` directly. Example:

```
template<class T>
using fun_t = T*(T*);

template<auto fun_ptr, class T>
void start_thread_safer(T* params)
{
    auto callback = [](void* vparams) -> void* {
        return fun_ptr(static_cast<T*>(vparams));
    };
    start_thread(callback, params);
}
```

Now you could type-safely use:

```
track_t* Loop (track_t* params);
start_thread_safer<Loop>(&track);
```

---

There is an optimisation that allows one to avoid indirection: Since `unsigned char` is guaranteed to fit within the memory of `void*`, you can pass the object within that memory directly. With integers (such as `unsigned char`), this is simple:

```
str::uintptr_t temp = track;
start_thread (Loop, reinterpret_cast<void*>(temp));

// in Loop
track_t track = reinterpret_cast<str::uintptr_t>(params);
```

If the passed type is not an integer, but is trivially copyable and fits within the pointer, following works as well:

```
void* params = nullptr;
static_assert(sizeof params >= sizeof track);
std::memcpy(&params, &track, sizeof track);
start_thread (Loop, params);

// in Loop
track_t track;
std::memcpy(&track, &params, sizeof track);
```

This optimisation also improves safety because there is no longer any indirection, and thus you can no longer fail to keep a pointed parameter alive until its usage.

I'll leave it as an exercise to combine these approaches.

Comment: Please do not reward these kinds of defective questions with answers that are basically random guesses, and nothing more. Without a [mre], no authoritative answer is possible. The problem described in the question is just as likely as having nothing to do with type-safety. `start_thread()` sounds like something that starts a new execution thread, `std::thread` or POSIX; and the problem can be as simple as `track` going out of scope and getting destroyed in the original thread before the new execution thread gets into gear. There's just no way to know, without an improved question.

Comment: ``start_thread ()`` is part of the PiGPIO library. See the link in my original question. And: My question is **not** a debug request (not yet at least).